# Kunneth spectral sequence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, abstract-algebra

In Rotman's *Homological Algebra*, 1st edition, there is written:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is every detail of 11.31-11.35 correct? Isn't the spectral sequence in 11.35 1st quadrant and not 3rd quadrant? Do 11.34-35 also hold without the assumption of positivity, making them 1st & 4th quadrant? I'm asking, because Universal Coefficient and Kunneth split exact sequences do not need positivity. Isn't $Hom(A_\ast,C_\ast)$ a chain complex, so we should write $H_n$ instead of $H^n$?

If $R$ is hereditary, then 11.34,35 should become 11.31,32. If $B$ is $\ldots\!\to\!0\!\to\!0\!\to\! M \!\to\!0\!\to\!0\!\to\!\ldots$, then 11.31,32 should become 8.22,26. But as it stands, they do not.

I suspect that 11.32 should be $$0\to\prod_{p+q=n-1}Ext^1_R(H_pA,H_qB)\to H_n(Hom_R(A,B))\to\!\!\!\prod_{p+q=n}\!\!\!Hom_R(H_pA,H_qB)\to0$$ and in 11.35 we should have $\prod_{s+t=q}$ instead of $\coprod_{s+t=q}$? Can anyone reliably confirm this?

If $A_\ast$ and $B_\ast$ are singular chain complexes $S_\ast(X)$ and $S_\ast(Y)$, what do 11.32 and 11.35 tell us?

By the way, $A_\ast\otimes B_\ast$ and $Hom(A_\ast,B_\ast)$ are chain complexes, defined by:
[image]
[image]

Comment: If $R$ is hereditary, then $Ext^p_R$ and $Tor_p^R$ are $0$, except for $p\!=\!0,1$, so we have nonzero terms only in two columns. Since we are on the second page, all differentials are $0$, hence $E_2=E_\infty$ and $E^2=E^\infty$. Thus $n$-th diagonal (filtration of $H_n(Hom(A,B))$ and $H_n(A\otimes B)$) gives the exact sequence. But the result does not agree with 11.34 ($n$-th diagonal gives $\prod_{t-s=n-1}$).

Comment: What is the grading convention for $Hom(A,C)$?  $Hom(A,C)_m=\oplus Hom _{l-k=m}(A_k,C_l)$?

Comment: Which one is "second" theorem?  Another point : since there isn't really a question of variance, a chain complex can be considered as cochain complex by negating the degree and vice versa.

Comment: The positivity is required to guarantee the convergence.  The positivity assures that there are only finite differentials for given bidegree.

Comment: I think the discrepancy between theorem 11.32 and 11.34 simply come from the grading convention.  I guess in Theorem 11.32 C is supposed to be a positively graded cochain complex, which is considered as a negatively graded chain complex in theorem 11.34.

Comment: @user43326 Are you sure that the spectral sequence does not converge when there are nonzero pieces in the fourth quadrant? Positivity is sufficient, but I suspect not required, for convergence. I can't find these two spectral sequences in any other book. Any suggestions? Also, the grading convention does not explain $n+1$ instead of $n-1$.

Comment: It is true that the positivity is not necessary for convergence, but there is no other easy sufficient condition.  (There is a paper by Boardman on the subject, conditional convergent spectral sequences, among others).  As to the grading convention, in Theorem 11.32 and 8.26, C is negatively graded, in Theorem 11.32 Ext $(H_*(A),H_*(C))$ is negatively graded as well, and in Theorem 11.34, everything is positively graded.  So the sum in 11.34 becomes difference in 11.32, which explains n-1 in 8.26 instead of 8.22

Comment: A similar thread is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346597/formulation-of-k%C3%BCnneth-theorems-definition-of-mathrmhom-and-otimes-of-c).