# Zeroth cohomology of tensor product of complexes concentrated in nonpositive degrees

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

This is probably an easy problem, but I can't find any reference.

Let $V$ and $W$ be cochain complexes over some commutative ring, and assume that they have both cohomologies concentrated in nonpositive degrees. Let $V \otimes^{\mathbb L} W$ be the derived tensor product. There is a natural morphism
\begin{align}
H^0(V) \otimes H^0(W) &\to H^0(V \otimes^{\mathbb L} W), \\
[f] \otimes [g] &\mapsto [f \otimes g]
\end{align}

For a while I was convinced that in order for this to be an isomorphism, one would need to invoke some
Künneth-like result, but now I think that this can be elementarly proved to be bijective.

*Idea*: using resolutions, one can replace $V$ and $W$ with quasi-isomorphic complexes which are strictly in nonpositive degrees and also homotopically flat, so that we don't need to derive the tensor product. Then, the map
\begin{align}
H^0(V \otimes^{\mathbb L} W) &\to H^0(V) \otimes H^0(W), \\
[f \otimes g]  &\mapsto [f] \otimes [g]
\end{align}
is well defined and it is the inverse of the above natural morphism.

Am I missing something? I'd be very interested in a reference, in any case.

Comment: The Künneth spectral sequence (cf https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165714/kunneth-spectral-sequence) has only $p=q=0$ contributing to $H_0$, and since it is a first quadrant spectral sequence here are no ingoing or outgoing differentials in this group, so $H_0 = E^2_{0,0} = H_*(V)\otimes_R H_*(W)$. Unraveling the construction of the spectral sequence gives your proof.